# Node Web Server Callbacks

Tags: node.js

What is the best way to handle callbacks in a server? I have quite a few callbacks and have structured the files nicely but looking for a way to stash the response object for later use.

I understand anonymous functions keep the variable scope inside the function. ie this works fine with multiple requests:

```
const http = require('http')
const _xmlToJson = new require("xml2js").Parser({explicitArray: false})

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    var xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <note>
      <to>You</to>
      <from>Me</from>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
      <body>Get Some Milk</body>
    </note>`

    _xmlToJson.parseString(xml, function(error, json){
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        response.end(JSON.stringify(json))
    })
}).listen(process.env.PORT);
```

In single request applications I often store the callback but with more than one request the _state which is global gets overwritten. I would like to use functions like below but this pattern I'm assuming is not going to work for web server code.

```
const http = require('http')
const _xmlToJson = new require("xml2js").Parser({explicitArray: false})

var _state

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    _state = {
        httpResponse: response
    }

    var xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <note>
      <to>You</to>
      <from>Me</from>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
      <body>Get Some Milk</body>
    </note>`

    _xmlToJson.parseString(xml, xmlToJsonComplete)
}).listen(process.env.PORT);

function xmlToJsonComplete(error, json){
    _state.httpResponse.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    _state.httpResponse.end(JSON.stringify(json))
}
```

I am just wondering what solutions there are to this. I thought about using Session but then it wouldn't be Restful. Or should I be using the async pattern.

Comment: you simply don't need _state.

Comment: It also seems quite weird to create XML, and then immediately convert it to json. why not just create json?

Comment: but if I don't stash the response somewhere how do I call it from the callback function?

Comment: Pass it to the callback function using an anonymous function.

Comment: that was just a sample of using a callback.

Comment: There's literally no reason to use the second code compared to the first. You're just overcomplicating it for no discernable gain. There's 0 reason to do it that way.

Comment: I have about 8 callbacks in total and was trying to avoid the nested structure.

Comment: Regardless, what you need is a way of accessing `req` and `res` from each of those callbacks. Your options are: Define the callbacks within the callback such that it closes around request/response (code sample 1), or, pass req/resp into said callbacks by calling them within an anonymous function (which isn't any  more efficient or clean than sample 1)

Comment: Is there a way to store the response object some other way? In ASPNET there was Environment (global), Application (life of request) and Session. Is there something like Application? Passing it around is a little messy.

Comment: Application, no, because it'd be shared across all requests. Session, yes-ish, but it wouldn't help with `response` due to the fact that it's for this one request, not every request in the session. So, realistically, no, nothing like that would be useful for this purpose, but both Application and Session can be useful for some things (just not req/res)

Comment: I guess in the ASPNET world the 'class' is initalised for the request, So using a private variable in a class (like _state) wouldn't be shared. You'd have to use a const to make shared. Getting used to Node.

Comment: Yeah, i'm not too familiar with asp, but i assume it works like php for example, where you're dealing with a single request in the code. with node.js, `_state` would be re-used for each request, which is why storing `response` on it would be a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes, it does seem quite obvious now. Thanks @Kevin B.

```
const http = require('http')
const _xmlToJson = new require("xml2js").Parser({explicitArray: false})

var _state

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    _state = {
        httpResponse: response
    }

    var xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <note>
      <to>You</to>
      <from>Me</from>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
      <body>Get Some Milk</body>
    </note>`

    _xmlToJson.parseString(xml, function(error, json){
        xmlToJsonComplete(json, response)
    })
}).listen(process.env.PORT);

function xmlToJsonComplete(json, response){
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    response.end(JSON.stringify(json))
}
```